# Is there an SQL function that you can exclude results with integer and characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number of records in my results that follow the following format:

`TJ12345`

So, any 2 characters followed by a set of integers. Is there a way I can exclude these records from my results?

Other records within the results have all characters for at least the first three letters so;

`tfydu734`, `fdsha21344`, `hdsifhsidufh2`

```
SELECT name, Filername 
FROM [Permissions] with (nolock) 
WHERE  (Name like '" & txtSearch.Text & "' 
           or ACEName like '" & txtSearch.Text & "') 
           and (ACEName not like '%Error%' 
           and ACEName not like '%nas_%'
           and ACEName not like '%NASA%')
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is the database being used? what have you tried?

Comment: It depends on exact DBMS you're using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: @vkp Updated what i have so far, i have no idea where to start with regards specific characters. I need to exclude "name" results that begin with CHAR, CHAR, INT

Comment: Side note - you might want to take a peek at this article as it seems you are using the NOLOCK hint. It is not a magic go fast button. It brings a lot of other effects to the table that most people don't realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You might want to clear up the differences between _characters_, _integers_, _letters_, _digits_, _punctuation_, _symbols_, ... . Is ";)FortyTwo" included because it is two characters followed by an integer? Are both uppercase and lowercase letters acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Other records within the results have all characters for at least the first three letters

so you could simply use

```
WHERE ACEName LIKE '[A-z][A-z][A-z]%'
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, just on this, what is the symbol for if it is an integer e.g. [1-9] ??

Comment: Well, rather `[0-9]`. But if you don't know at which position the first integer is, you'll need a `%` before it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, task "determine if string contains two letters followed by digits" can be solved like:

```
declare @x nvarchar(max)
select @x = 'TJ12345'
select 
   case 
        when @x like '[A-z][A-z]%' and isnumeric(right(@x, len(@x) - 2)) = 1 then 1 
        else 0 
   end as Should_Be_Excluded
```

Key idea: first check if it starts with two letters, then strip them out and check if remaining string contains only digits using `isnumeric` fuction.

So literally you need to invert this criteria and put it into `where` condition in order to exclude these records.

```
select * 
from your_table
where 
    your_field not like '[A-z][A-z]%' 
    or isnumeric(right(your_field, len(your_field) - 2)) = 0
```

Comment: How would i add this to the statement above^^

Comment: i need to exclude any results that have an integer at position 3. does that make it any easier?

Comment: @A.C See update. But note - if your real exclude criteria is just "not a digit at position 3" then it is much more simpler. just use `isnumeric(substring(your_field, 2, 1))`

Comment: `isnumeric` is notoriously 'surprising'. It accepts `+`, `-`, currency symbols and exponential notation. `TF123E5` would pass the test.

Comment: @RemusRusanu oh... you're right. Well, in the case of SQL Server 2012 it's better to use `try_parse`. Otherwise these extrasymbols should be handled separately in condition - sad but true....